# How to generate parameter based on another one in .net template

Tags: .net, templates

I have a .net template in my template.json configured like this

```
{
  ...
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "solution"
  },
  "sourceName": "MyCustomTemplate",
  "sources": [
    {
        "rename": {
          "Smth.WebSolution.sln": "Smth.MyCustomTemplate.sln"
        }
    }
  ],
"symbols": {
    "MyCustomName": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "datatype": "string",
      "description": "MyServiceName without a dash. Example = nameservice.",
      "FileRename": "MyCustomName",
      "isRequired": true,
      "defaultValue": "WasMotRenamed"
    }
  }
}
```

I have "MyCustomTemplate" pattern in names of files like Smth.MyCustomTemplate.sln, also in the code and it works ok for me. Also as i understand it is possible to write MyCustomTemplate i a way like mycustomtemplate and it will replace the values in lower case.

What I also need to do is to have file names like smthmycustomtemplate
For example i run a command

```
dotnet new shortName -o Test
```

and I need to get some files named like Smth.Test.sln and others like smthtest.txt

what i do now is `dotnet new shortName -o Test --MyCustomName = smthtest`

Is it possible to configure the template like that so the symbol could be made based on anothe value in json, or I have to set the file names in some way?